# fix digits after decimal points in R using rd() function for the value 0

Tags: r, decimal-point

I am trying to format numbers as 4 numbers points after the decimal points (.XXXX). I use rd() function. For some reason for the value 0.000000 the command does not work.

```
library('weights')
x=0.000000
y=rd(x, digits=4)
print(y)
.00000000
```

Comment: does `format(0, nsmall = 4)` work instead? I'm not sure what `rd` gives you besides [removing a leading 0](https://github.com/cran/weights/blob/master/R/rd.r#L16)

Comment: the reason that I use rd() is that I want to remove the leading 0. the format should be .xxxx

Comment: `rd(x, digits=4, add=FALSE)`